# Why does filename expansion not work in this example?

Tags: bash, sudo, filenames, wildcards

I remove some files using `trash-cli`:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/test
$ sudo trash mfile 
$
```

Then I look for where the deleted file is stored:

```
$ sudo ls /.Trash/0/ -la
total 16
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 May 19 16:52 .
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 May 19 16:52 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 19 16:52 files
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 19 16:52 info

$ sudo ls /.Trash/0/* -la
ls: cannot access '/.Trash/0/*': No such file or directory

$ sudo ls /.Trash/0/files/ -la
total 12
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 19 16:52 .
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 May 19 16:52 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 t    t       6 May 19 16:48 mfile
```

Why does filename expansion not work in the second command?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you putting your switches after the directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `ls` shows that `/.Trash/0/` is only readable by root (the first line, the one for `.`). Since you're using `sudo`, you probably aren't root, so your shell can't list the contents of the directory and can't expand the `*`. `ls /.Trash/0/` without the `sudo` would probably give `Permission denied`.

This is similar to how `sudo echo foo > /some/path/filename` doesn't work, if `/some/path` is writable only by root: The shell processes expansions and redirections before running `sudo`. You'd need `sudo bash -c 'ls /.Trash/0/*'` or such to have the command line processed under `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks. By `sudo`, didn't I get superuser privillege to read `/.Trash/0/`?

Comment: Sure you did, @Tim, but the shell performs pathname expansion on the (whole) command *before* executing it.  In this case, that means it does the expansion with your ordinary, unprivileged identity, because it is only by running the (expanded) command that you obtain privilege.  By then, it is too late.